# Vista fails to load user profile if i dont choose user account quickly

Tags: windows-vista, user-profiles, i18n

i know this question is kind of vague, but here´s what i know.
When i turn on the computer and the user account selection screen shows up, if I choose a user right away everything works properly. But if I leave that screen for a while (not sure how much, about two minutes, less maybe ?) and then choose a user, my profile fails to load as if the user path (c:\users\myuser) couldn´t be found. It shows a blank desktop, it can´t connect to the internet, some programs misbehave, etc.

I have Windows Vista Home Premium SP 2, in Spanish (my guess is this has something to do with path translation "c:\usuarios\" vs "c:\users\").

if there´s any more info (my lap hardware, etc) that could be helpful please let me know

Comment: Please can you scan your PC for viruses using malwarebytes anti-malware scanner and let us know the results? Sounds like an infection to me.

Comment: Using the built-in Administrator account create a new user profile.  See if the problem surfaces on a new user profile.  Update your question with everything you find once you do this.

Comment: Does it happen with *any* user?